# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926 throw err;

Tags: node.js

I am still learning and very new to coding. I have been getting this error since yesterday. I have tried uninstalling node and so I can reinstall node again hoping to resolve this issue, but there is problem uninstalling. any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall "NodeJs" completely. Delete "NPM" & "NPM-Cache" from

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming

if you dont see the NPM-Cache folder still go ahead
and restart the PC. and again install everything freshly.

To open the AppData folder on Windows 10, 8 & 7:
Open File Explorer/Windows Explorer (Press the Windows button on your keyboard).
Type/Search for  %AppData% into the address bar and hit enter.
Navigate to the required folder (Roaming or Local)